# When are C# static Func properties generated? During app startup or when first accessed?

Tags: c#, .net

I was watching a C# learning video and in it, the author has some `private static readonly Func<....> GetMoviesAsync = ....;` property.

[image]

The author says that these static properties are generated/compiled on app startup.

I thought static properties are generated on *first access* .. not app startup?

Comment: You could test for yourself by invoking some code that you can log or set a breakpoint in. You don't need to ask us anything that you can test for yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure -how- to test this out @jmcilhinney ??? can you please explain? Remember, this is about app start vs first-access. If i put a breakpoint on the static property, i don' know if that was resolved _when I broke  on it_ or it was already done during startup?  (side note: thanks for the -1. great way to support new people, coming to SO / learning / etc. Maybe that explains why I got pained looks from my collegues when I suggested I might ask about this, on SO).

Comment: Do you mind posting a link to the video?

Comment: The exact timing is actually undefined, unless the class has a static constructor (in which case the static fields will be initialised when the class is first accessed rather than at some unspecified time before). See here for more details: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/BeforeFieldInit

Comment: @Orion - here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxqAUIYemMs

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any precise moment. If there is a static constructor, then all static properties are guaranteed to be initialized before the constructor's body is executed. If there is no static ctor, then static properties are guaranteed to be initialized before the class is first used. This "before" that I'm talking about is not strictly defined afaik. At any moment CLR deems fit, I suppose.